# Problem retriving the post type category

Tags: terms

I have a small isuue, this code retrive me the parent categories from a post type.

The post_type is : serial
The taxonomy is : seriale

```
<?php 
$terms = get_terms('seriale','child_of=668');foreach ($terms as $term) {echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';}
?>
```

The problem is: after i added another post in my site it my theme it aprear on all duplicate.

EX: First post - i select Year 2011
     Second post - i select Year 2012

In archive it retrive me for the first and second post...

:2011,2012 ...

I want to be able to get only wath i select...
I want to get categories only for child_of=668

Wath im doing rong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) retrieves all terms in a taxonomy, not terms added to a post.

you want to use [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) to retrieve terms assigned to a specific post. there are no additional arguments to filter the list of terms returned, you'll have to manually check a term's parent to only output terms that are a child of a specific term id.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'seriale' );
foreach( $terms as $term ):
    if( 668 == $term->parent ){
        echo $term->name;
    }
endforeach;
```